# DC Comics Special: Girls of Superman and Lois Lane

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, superman

DC published a one-shot comics sometime around 2003-2004.

In this issue, it featured many female superheroes, all of whom were the children of Clark Kent and Lois Lane.

Please help me find it. I do not remember any more details, other than it was around the size of specials that used to be published around that time (probably 100 pages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't an exact match, but it sounds as if you are misremembering [JLA: Created Equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JLA:_Created_Equal). In it,

> A cosmic storm passes through the planet Earth, bringing with it a mysterious plague which nearly kills the entire male population (an event later referred to as the Fall). The only two men who survive are Superman and his archenemy Lex Luthor... Superman and Lois Lane's son, Adam Kent, is the first newborn male since the storm hit, and more are born through Superman's DNA, granting them Kryptonian powers.

Comment: Yesh!!You nailed it! Thanks a lot!